# UTC time string to local time zone string.

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i am getting UTC time from server and i need to display this time base on local timezone,here is my code

```
NSString *UTCtime = @"10:30";
NSDateFormatter * frmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[frmt setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *localTime = [frmt dateFromString:UTCtime];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Changing TimeZone for a time:

First, convert UTC time string into `NSDate`:

```
NSString *UTCtime = @"10:30";

NSDateFormatter *frmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[frmt setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
[frmt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

NSDate *utcTime = [frmt dateFromString:UTCtime];
```

Then calculate the time difference in seconds from UTC for current timezone:

```
NSInteger timeZoneDiff = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
```

Add that time difference to the `NSDate` UTC time calculated above

```
NSDate *localTime = [utcTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneDiff];
```